# How to navigate to a View Controller embedded in tab bar controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `viewControllerA` embedded in a `navigationController`.From this `viewControllerA` I want to navigate to another `viewControllerB` which is embedded in a `tabBarController`.
So I have a setup like -

1. `viewControllerB` is embedded in a `navigationController` and then this is embedded in `tabBarController`.
2. In `viewControllerA` I have a button from where I want to push to `viewControllerB`.

This is what I am trying to do -

```
-(void)areaBtnClicked:(id)sender{
      NSLog(@"btn clicked");
      UITabBarController *tbc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabController"];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:tbc animated:YES];
}
```

However the app is crashing with a error message as -

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

Comment: Hey, there is better to have tabbar controller as a root. And Than have navigation controller as tabs.
Probably you can think to reorganize yours controllers flow?

Comment: @DoN1cK - well its something like login flow where u can login and then navigate to main controllers that are embedded in tabs.

Comment: Than maybe you can separate them? after login done, remove all controllers and put your tabbar as a root.

Comment: Check that you have a UITabBarController with identifier == tabController

Comment: Yes storyboard identifier is correct

Answer (score 0):

Are you sured, that your controller has that identifier "tabController" ?
Check your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently deleting the app from simulator solved the problem.